# Ember: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined, Anchoring to the same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js, anchor

I was using the tip of a user from this problem. [Ember and Anchor link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18445661/ember-js-anchor-link)

My Problem is, that I'd like to link something on the same page, which is index.
But If I come from imprint, it does not work, because top is not defined.

app.js:

```
var App = Ember.Application.create({
  LOG_TRANSITIONS: true
});

App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    events: {
        goToLink: function(item, anchor) {
            var $elem = $(anchor);
            var $scrollTo = $('body').scrollTop($elem.offset().top);

            this.transitionToRoute(item.route).then($scrollTo);  //.transitionTo is depricated
        }
    }
});

App.Router.map(function() {
  this.route('imprint', { path: "/imprint" });
});
```

index.html:

```
<script type='text/x-handlebars' data-template-name="application">
<a href="#/" {{action 'goToLink' "index" "#ThomasWurster"}}>Thomas Wurster</a>
</script>

<script type='text/x-handlebars' data-template-name="index">
<a id="ThomasWurster">blubb</a>
</script>

<script type='text/x-handlebars' data-template-name="imprint">
Imprint
</script>
```

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question, but if your problem is that `offset().top` might return `NaN` (or `False`), why don't you assume it should be zero? -> `...scrollTop($elem.offset().top or 0);`

Comment: Why should it be zero if I want to scroll to a certain position, after visiting the correct page.

Comment: could you please link this with a fiddle and what are you expecting after clicking on the anchor ?

Comment: No, I can't. 
http://birgitpohl.github.io/ImmobilienWurster/imprint.html
This is plain HTML and CSS, klick on the first link for example to see, what should happen.

From imprint I klick on a link, which takes me to index and to a certain position.


Since Ember uses the hashes, to build a page in one single page in the same way, I am having trouble, changing the page AND to go to a vertain position.

Because .top does not work, since the HTML element is not in imprint.
The code only works on index/in the same page where the element is.