# Ember js LinkTo section in another route

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I am trying to link to a section in another route. I looked online and cannot find a way to do this basic function in Ember JS.

I have tried:

```
href="someRoute#section" // does not work
```

and

```
<LinkTo @route="someRoute#section">Link</LinkTo> // someRoute#section route does not exist
```

Does anyone know of a way of getting this to work. I am using Ember Octane so I can use anything available in there to help.

Comment: `<LinkTo>` component only accept a route name ==> https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/925bee3eda2f31083f4e96ed653e9f7f8cb19a02/packages/%40ember/-internals/glimmer/lib/components/link-to.ts#L280, but you can use `queryParams` to send element id for scroll and then use html api to scroll the page... or use some addons like this ==>https://github.com/peopleconnectus/ember-concurrency-scroll

Answer (score 1):

you may use this addon `ember-href-to` and use this like

Click [here](https://github.com/intercom/ember-href-to) to see about the above addon. 
Nice example is available there. you may refer those.

Answer (score 1):

Ember does not have a native way to link to particular elements in the DOM. This is true for both the angle-bracket `<LinkTo />` component and the curly component `{{#link-to}}`. There does, however, seem to be a hack to provide this feature -> [Ember.js anchor link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18445661/ember-js-anchor-link).