# Using HTML anchors in Ember.js

Tags: html, ember.js, handlebars.js

In my Ember application, how can I jump to an HTML anchor inside one of my Handlebars templates? [I created a jsFiddle that shows what I want to accomplish](http://jsfiddle.net/Abdull/KUkd6/).

**Background**
Ember's model of navigation through an application uses HTML anchors.

I have the following requirement: when a user clicks on a Handlebar `linkTo` helper to navigate to a new *route destination*, the browser should automatically scroll to an anchor inside the Handlebars template associated to that new *route destination*.

Comment: what [type of url](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/specifying-the-location-api/) are you using? By default Ember uses hash (#), which will collide with anchors. Technically, you could use scrollspy (or something similar) if you implement [hashbang (#!)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14929170/hashbang-urls-using-ember-js) client urls.

Comment: @MilkyWayJoe I'm using Ember's default hash-based navigation. I just gave the history-based navigation a try, but it didn't work in both my own app and my jsFiddle mentioned above (Exception "`No route matched the URL '/_display/'"`)... thank you for the scrollspy and hashbang suggestions which I will now investigate.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ember.js anchor link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18445661/ember-js-anchor-link)

Answer (score 0):

Use `jquery` to scroll to a particular section.

```
$('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("a[name='someAnchor']").offset().top
});
```

Refer [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6677069/3244627) regarding the same.

To scroll to the anchor after the view is rendered override the `didInsertElement` in your definition for your route's View.

Refer [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8882168/3244627) regarding the same.

```
App.LonglistView = Ember.View.extend({
    didInsertElement: function() {
        // Place the scroll to anchor code here.
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("a[name='someAnchor']").offset().top
        });
     }
});
```

Here is [a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/KUkd6/2/) in jsfiddle ( I have not added any data models for clarity )

EDIT: You could also use non-jquery way to do the scrolling

```
document.getElementsByTagName('a')[name='someAnchor'].scrollIntoView()
```

The [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/KUkd6/3/) for the same.