# Emberjs Change routes to !# for seo?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, seo, middleman

Is it possible to change emberjs routes to !# so the page content can be parsed by Google?

I'm setting up middleman + emberjs, and I'm trying to figure out an easy way to make my pages crawlable.

Comment: what do u mean by !# ? how is your URL already?

Comment: check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14929170/hashbang-urls-using-ember-js