# Ember routing: Changing Ember.Location's pathname

Tags: ember.js

My ember app resides at the URL `[server]/app`. With ember's default hashlocation, URLs will turn out to be `[server]/app#/[path]`, not `[server]/app/#/[path]`. How can I change the Ember.Location.pathname from `/app` to `/app/` to make the URL work?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I change the Ember.Location.pathname from /app to /app/ to make the URL work?

One way you could achieve this would be to change the default location to `history`

```
App.Router.reopen({
  location: 'history'
});
```

See [here](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/specifying-the-location-api/) for more info on that.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. I want to keep location at hash though. I need to make the ember router play nice with current URL setup I have (rails namespaced to `/app`). The solution I'm looking for is almost like this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14929170/hashbang-urls-using-ember-js