# emberjs dynamic route with hash only (no slashes)

Tags: url, hash, ember.js, routes

Even if everything is in the title, to be clear, I would like my emberjs *dynamic routes* to look like:

http://mywebsite.com/#dynamic_route/subroute

with hash only, instead of the one with '/' by default:

http://mywebsite.com/#/dynamic_route/subroute

Not sure if it's possible (I tried several hacks without success) but if yes let me know :)

Thanks,
Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Up to version 1.0.0-pre.4 this seemed to be the default behaviour. In final version 1.0.0 it only behaves like this for routes without paths. An approach i have followed and seems to work fine is by providing an implementation for the location API (http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/specifying-the-location-api/) and it is based on the default implementation discussed in,
https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/2053answers 
and
[Hashbang URLs using Ember.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14929170/hashbang-urls-using-ember-js)

```
(function() {

    var get = Ember.get, set = Ember.set;

    Ember.Location.registerImplementation('no-slashes', Ember.HashLocation.extend({   
        getURL: function() {
            var path = get(this, 'location').hash;
            if(path.indexOf("/")!=1){
                return "/"+path.substr(1);
            }else{
                return path.substr(1);  
            }
        },

        onUpdateURL: function(callback) {
            var self = this;
            var guid = Ember.guidFor(this);
            Ember.$(window).bind('hashchange.ember-location-'+guid, function() {
                Ember.run(function() {
                    var path = location.hash.substr(1);
                    if(path.indexOf("/")!=0){
                        path = "/"+path;
                    }
                    if (get(self, 'lastSetURL') === path) { return; }
                    set(self, 'lastSetURL', null);
                    callback(path);
                });
            });
        }

    }));

})();
App.Router.reopen({
    location: 'no-slashes'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

@melc Thanks for pointing me in right direction. I improvised the code. Note - I am using ember 1.5.1.

I ended up overriding only getURL method. registerImplementation is deprecated in 1.5.1 so using the container to register the new implementation of HashLocation. Hope this helps someone.

```
(function() {

var get = Ember.get, set = Ember.set;

var noSlashLocation = Ember.HashLocation.extend({
    getURL: function() {
        var hash = this.getHash().substr(1);
        return (hash.indexOf('/') != 0) ? '/'+hash : hash;            
    }
});

var container = new Ember.Container();
container.register('location:no-slash', noSlashLocation);

Ember.Router.reopen({
    location: container.lookup('location:no-slash')
});

})();
```