# Routing With Ember Issues

Tags: ember.js

I have my router for my application setup like this:

```
App.Router.map(function(){
    this.resource('users', function() {
        this.route('new');
     });
});
```

However when I try and navigate to /#users i get the error message

> Assertion failed: The URL '/users.index' did not match any routes in
>   your application

Likewise when I try and navigate to /#users/new I get

> Assertion failed: The URL '/users/new.index' did not match any routes
>   in your application

I have the following routes setup as well:

```
App.UsersRoute = Ember.Route.extend({});

App.UsersNewRoute = Ember.Route.extend({});
```

I am using Ember 1.3.2

Anyone have any suggestions on why I am receiving these errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The routes will work if you enter a slash after the hash i.e. `#/users` and `#/users/new`.
However if you also want it to work whether the slash exists or not then you can try the following,

[emberjs dynamic route with hash only (no slashes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18511218/emberjs-dynamic-route-with-hash-only-no-slashes/19132794#19132794)

you can also find an example with your routes here,

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OzOYUxU/1#users

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OzOYUxU/1#users/new

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OzOYUxU/1/edit