# How to redirect old hash URLs to hash bang in Ember.js?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, hashbang

I use this method:

[Hashbang URLs using Ember.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14929170/hashbang-urls-using-ember-js)

And now i have website with hashbangs. But people come also to old URLs with only hash, but without hashbang.

So how to change URL from only hash to hashbang if someone visits the old style url?

Comment: The tricky part is how to change them back if you switch away from hashbangs in the future.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite I don't think i will ever need to do this. help with my question would be approciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think you need to tweak ember for that. Simple solution is before ember application loads you can run the following code.

```
    var url = window.location.toString();

    if(url.split('#!').length==1) {
      if(url.split('#').length==2) {
        window.location = url.split('#')[0]+'#!' + url.split('#')[1];
      }
    }
```

Basically what it does is rewrites the url to #!.

**UPDATE:** Else one more way is write above code in Ember Initializers.

Here is the jsbin http://emberjs.jsbin.com/aLiretO/1#post