# Emberjs Hashbang is getting Uncaught ReferenceError: set is not defined

Tags: javascript, ember.js, hashbang

I implemented the ember.js hashbang via ember-cli. So in my app/initializer folder I have an application.js that contains the solution from this previous question:
[Hashbang URLs using Ember.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14929170/hashbang-urls-using-ember-js)

When I run the code it works great but when I go to another route I get:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: set is not defined
```

But when I refresh the page it loads just fine until I try to go to another route.

SO

example.com/#!/

will load

example.com/#!/nextRoute

I get a Transition #1: TRANSITION COMPLETE. but nothing Renders on the page

Comment: Where (what line) does the error occur?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may not be a surprise to you to hear that the problem is that `set` is undefined.

In the original implementation of `HashBangLocation` that you linked to, there is a line at the top

```
var get = Ember.get, set = Ember.set;
```

In your re-implementation inside an initializer, I do not see this line. JSHint would probably find this error for you. If you look at the transpiled code, there is no definition of `set` in sight.

To fix this, add the `var get = Ember.get, set = Ember.set` line back into your code, or use `self.set('lastSetURL', null);` instead.

So if there's no `set`, how did `get` manage to work? It turns out there is a bug in Ember. At one point in the source, `get` is declared in global scope.